# iPad Table view

Tags: ipad

Is it possible to dynamically load the Table view, ie taking data from database and load the Table view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you'd like a more detailed answer than that, you probably ought to provide some additional information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually i wnat to implement a tree view in iPad, i am using Navigation Controller for implementing that, i want populate the the Table View dynamically. I would like to take data from SQLite database and load it into Table View.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It depends on what type of data base you are using. You can fetch data using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`..